# Tradução da aba obtido e todos

Tags: bug, tradução, localização, medalhas

Como os textos falam em medalhas, feminino, a aba todos e obtidos devem esta no feminino também

todas e obtidas.

ex

> todas as medalhas foram entregues.
>
> As medalhas obtidas durante as olimpiadas foram esquecidas.